# changing url with get paramater in .htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to change my url using htaccess but it doesn't seem to be working. I want http://example.com/blog_view?id=1 to be changed to http://example.com/blog-id/1/ but it isn't working. I have tried using this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog-id/([^/]*)/$ /blog_view?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser and what error are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: What does `it isn't working` mean? What happens? I don't understand from your question. Is there an e500 or what?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to add a `RewriteBase` directive:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog-id/([^/]*)/$ /blog_view?id=$1 [L]
```

You can test your rules with [this tool](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

Comment: I just used your code and same thing happened. It still directs to `http://example.com/blog_view?id=1` instead of `http://example.com/blog-id/1/` . I used the htaccess tester and it showed that `RewriteRule ^blog-id/([^/]*)/$ /blog_view?id=$1 [L]` - This rule was not met.

Answer (score 0):

You need one redirect and one rewrite rule (already existing):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog_view\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blog-id/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^blog-id/([^/]+)/?$ blog_view?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```